# On message event from telethon returns from_id None

Tags: telegram, telethon

I am getting an error when trying to access the from_id attribute from an message that has only media (photos, documents, voice, video) in it. Error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 467, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "d:\Code\asd\back.py", line 16, in on_message
    await pl.add_message(f'saved/{event.peer_id.user_id}/chat.json', event)
  File "d:\Code\asd\plugins.py", line 25, in add_message
    'author': event.from_id.user_id if event.from_id.user_id != None else event.peer_id.user_id,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_id'
```

No error appears when I send media, it only happens when I get the media send to me.
I hope some of you could help me finding an answer to my question.

I've been trying to use peer_id instead of from_id, but that didn't help eighter

Comment: SHow your code please

Comment: @0stone0 I dont think there is a need in my code. As I said its an message event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since the introduction of [Anonymous Admins](https://t.me/telegram/112), messages in Telegram chats can have no sender's.

You should be using the `message.sender_id` instead of `from_id`, in Telethon.

Reference: https://t.me/TelethonChat/126622

Comment: What if I need the chat used to send the message?

Comment: You can use [message.chat_id](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.chatgetter.ChatGetter.chat)